# Own implementation of Random Number Distribution for C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, random, distribution

I need to implement my own random number distribution class in C++11, but I can't find a minimalistic implementation to get me started.

I have already searched the gcc source code, but only found the header files and not the implementations of the different non-uniform distributions.

Can you point me to a simple yet complete example of a non-uniform distribution class in C++11 or post one here?

Comment: The random number library is header-only, and the headers provided by libstdc++ contain everything you want to know.

Comment: In the header-files I always see two overloaded ()-operators in the different distribution classes. The first calls the second, but the second one seems not to be implemented.

Comment: The doctor prescribes more coffee, [more perseverance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/596781) and a healthy dose of `grep`: It's all in `bits/random.tcc`.

Comment: I guess implementing your own distribution is nothing too exotic, so I assume that other people could also benefit from a _simple_ example which is readable and not spread over different files with strange endings. I've never looked into the gcc-source before.

Comment: The principle is simple [inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), but you have to take care to have the correct uniform input distribution (this is subtle). I guess this isn't something anyone should be doing who isn't willing to commit at least one afternoon's time of serious study to the subject, since a broken random distribution is worse than none.

Answer (score 4):

> I guess implementing your own distribution is nothing too exotic...

You guess wrong.  Luc Devroye wrote an [800 page book](http://luc.devroye.org/rnbookindex.html) on the topic. There is no single technique that works for all distributions. There are 4 general approaches:

1. Inversion - If the cumulative distribution function F<sub>X</sub>(b), -∞ < b < ∞, is a continuous and invertible function, then F<sub>X</sub>(X), the CDF applied to its own random variable, has a uniform(0,1) distribution.  Equate F<sub>X</sub>(X)=U and solve for X (if possible).
2. Convolution - Summing or differencing random variables yields a new distribution. For instance, the sum of two uniforms has a triangular distribution; or, the sum of n independent chi-squared(1)'s yields a chi-square(n)
3. Composition - Some complex distributions can be built up piecewise from simpler distributions using conditional probability.
4. Tricks/special relations - Leverage unique relationships between different distributions such as the fact that the square of a standard normal is a chi-squared(1) random variable; or that a chi-squared(2) is identical to an exponential(2). Together with Pythagoras' thm, these two facts are at the heart of the Box-Muller method for generating normals. Plot two independent standard normals together, and you get a 2-d vector from (0,0) which heads off in a uniform(0,2π) direction and has length `sqrt(exponential(2))`. Generate such a vector and convert it back to Cartesian coordinates using both sine and cosine transformations to yield the two independent normals.

Devroye's book fills in the details for many "popular" distributions, but since there are an infinite number of distributions out there an exhaustive treatment would be impossible.

Section 4.3 on page 59 of this [tutorial paper](http://www.informs-sim.org/wsc07papers/007.pdf) has one worked example for each of the four techniques sketched out above, and a proof of inversion on pages 60-62.

Comment: +1 and more info:  The standard provides both `piecewise_constant_distribution` and `piecewise_linear_distribution` which can fairly easily be used to approximate an arbitrary distribution.  If such an approximation is acceptable, and if you know the probability distribution you want, then these are easy-to-use viable alternatives.

Comment: P.S:  Nice tutorial paper!

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thanks, I find it hard to walk the tightrope between rigorously correct and accessible.